# Typescript and Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, decorator

I am learning the typescript also I am learning how to implement typescript in Node.js. Now, I have watched several videos and in those videos I found 2 methods to tie typescript with Node.js.
**One is by using decorators and other is by using the generic method type(by defining request and response types - Usage of interfaces.)**

The question is -> Which approach is preferable and which to use.(I am aware that there is no good or bad way I but still want to know the answer) In addition to performance, I also want to know which approach is easier for others to understand because in my opinion, both are quite difficult to understand.

Or is there any other and easier way to implement typescript with Node.JS?

Comment: Do you have a tsconfig in your project?

Comment: Yes @DubiousMaster

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least to me) - can you maybe add some code to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools to help run TS in NodeJS, such as `ts-node` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), but if you don't want to rely on that or, like me, can't figure out how to get it to work, you will want to have TS do what TS does, and transpile it to JS. Then in `package.json`, you'll want to have your start script reference the initial .js file.

To transpile TypeScript, simply use the command `tsc` if you have a tsconfig, or `tsc [starting file]` if you do not. This should compile the code first, and if compilation is successful, it will then transpile to JS in the designated folder.

In your package.json, ensure the command executed refers to the output folder's initial file. For example: `"start": "node dist/app"`

Comment: I know how to configure typescript with node.js but my question is actually different

Comment: Then I'm not entirely certain what your question really is. NodeJS is meant as a host for JavaScript, just so it can run. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do?